# Local Sensitivity Hashing for similarity matching

Tags: matching, similarity, lsh

Iam experimenting with the Local Sensitivity Hashing algorithm which I want to use to find patient similarities in computed tomography (CT) images.
I have build a Deep neural network extracting features. Now I want to take a images of a new patient, extract features and send them together with all other (training) patient features through the LSH algorithm to find the most similar one.

As the features are high dimensional I thought LSH would be a good choice.

Now Iam wondering how I should set the hyperparamters of the algorithm for such a task.
Should each patient get its own bucket. In example 100 patients, 100 buckets or should i just have one bucket and put all patients in this to get The nearest one?

All CT images contain the same anatomical structures.

Thanks for any advice,

Kind regards,

Michael